# Macro to copies value of a cell to another sheet but retain destination Format

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a Sheet named "Daily Data" and One Sheet named "JPY Dly".  I created a button and wrote a Macro to import data from another file and place into cells A1:D1 in "Daily Data".
[image]

I then need to Copy and Paste those VALUES into the next available cells in specific columns of Sheet "JPY Dly".

[image]

I used Offset in the Paste portion of the code but when the Paste occurs, the data does not keep the destination cells formatting.  All I want is the VALUES of the cells in "Daily Data" to be copied over and for them to assume the pre-determined formatting of cells in "JPY Dly".

Here is the code that I am using.

```
Sub Import_DailyData()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv"
'Opens the dowloaded file from the web

Workbooks("exchange.csv").Worksheets("exchange").Range("A8:AN9").Copy _
    Workbooks("FOREX TEST.xlsm").Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("A1")
'Copies the daily data into FOREX Workbook

Workbooks("exchange.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
'Closes the downloaded sheet without saving

Kill ("C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv")

'Insert the "Write to sheets" portion of the Sub in here

Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("A2").Copy Sheets("JPY Dly").Range("C2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("F2").Copy Sheets("JPY Dly").Range("E2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("G2").Copy Sheets("JPY Dly").Range("F2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("E2").Copy Sheets("JPY Dly").Range("G2000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'Below this you will see the ClearContents portion of the code
Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("A1:AN2").ClearContents


End Sub
```

Can you please tell me how to paste the Values only from "Daily Data" and them assume the formatting of the cells in "JPY Dly"?

**UPDATE**
Here is updated code recommended by chrisnielsen and the screenshot from the downloaded "exchange"file.

```
Sub Import_DailyData()

    Dim wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim wsCSV As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long

Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv")
Set wsCSV = wbCSV.Worksheets("exchange")
'Opens the dowloaded file from the web

Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JPY Dly")
'Copies the daily data into FOREX Workbook


'Closes the downloaded sheet without saving

'Insert the "Write to sheets" portion of the Sub in here

With wsDestination
        DestRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp) + 1
    
        ' Copy data
        .Cells(DestRow, 3).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 1).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 5).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 3).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 6).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 4).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 7).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 2).Value
End With
'Below this you will see the ClearContents portion of the code
'Worksheets("Daily Data").Range("A1:AN2").ClearContents
Workbooks("exchange.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
'Kill ("C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In Excel, you really need to be using Paste Special - Values to not upset existing formatting.

Comment: @ACCtionMan How do incorporate Paste Special - Values into my code and still use Offset?  I tried to add it at the end but I got a compile error.  Where do I add Paste special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Copy/Paste Values will work, it's cleaner to use the values properties of the source and destination cells.  This will retain destination cell formats.

Also, there are a number of other opertunities for improvement

1. Use Workbook and Workssheet references
2. No need for the intermediate Daily Data Sheet.
3. No need to repeat the .End(xlUp) bits
4. No need for the `( )` on the `Kill` line (in fact this has side effects that, while not a problem here, will eventually bite you)

```
Sub Import_DailyData()
    Dim wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim wsCSV As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    
    'Open the dowloaded file from the web, and get references
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv")
    Set wsCSV = wbCSV.Worksheets("exchange")
    
    ' Reference the destination
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JPY Dly") ' Assuming FOREX TEST.xlsm contains this code
    ' If FOREX TEST.xlsm does not contains this code, use this instead of the previous line
    'Set wsDestination = Application.Workbooks("FOREX TEST.xlsm").Worksheets("JPY Dly")
    
    ' get destination row
    With wsDestination
        DestRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
        ' Copy data
        .Cells(DestRow, 3).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 1).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 5).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 6).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 6).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 7).Value
        .Cells(DestRow, 7).Value = wsCSV.Cells(2, 5).Value
    End With
    
    'Close and delete the downloaded workbook without saving
    wbCSV.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill "C:\Users\dbrown1\Downloads\exchange.csv"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I received an error during the DestRow = .Range(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp) + 1  code ...Run time '1004' Method 'Range' of Object_worksheet failed.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Corrected now

Comment: This should be the preferred solution for this issue in every situation where all you are moving are the cell's values.  Copy/Paste should only be used as a way to easily move formats. Setting the cell's Value is far faster and more bulletproof (I had a user build a spreadsheet that took about 10 minutes to Copy/Paste row by row a mountain of data, she decided to do some other work at the same time and when she tried to use her clipboard, bad stuff happened).

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you so much for the correction.  The code now runs and does not error out.  But nothing is written to the cells in the destination sheet.  I am adding New Screenshots of the code and the "exchange" sheet when downloaded.

Comment: @D Brown - yep, there was another typo.  Added `.Row` to the `LastRow = ...` line (Note that the code before this correction would have added data at rows 40,000 something.  If you've saved your sheet after running it, check for extranious data that far downthe sheet (Use Ctrl-End) to find it)

Comment: @chrisneilsen  Thank you so much!!!  That is perfect!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Building on ACCitonMan's comment to use paste special.  The following code takes the text from cell A1 and pastes it into cell A2 while keeping whatever formatting is in cell A2.

```
Sub pasteSpec()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cRng As Excel.Range
    Dim pRng As Excel.Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Set cRng = ws.Range("A1")
    Set pRng = ws.Range("A2")
    
    cRng.Copy
    pRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'stops marching ants when using .copy
    
End Sub
```

Additional paste types can be found in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype).

Comment: That should do it.  Two minor tweaks to include Offset and maintaining destination formatting. Set pRng = cRng.Offset(1,0) gives you the same result as the above.  Also, the Paste:=xlPasteValues.

Comment: You can also avoid using Copy/Paste and use  pRng.Value = cRng.Value